# Getting White Lable Error with This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, lombok

I am using Spring boot. I am trying to use thymeleaf template. I have used lombok. I am getting WhiteLabel error while running the project that says There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/design.html ]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/design.html  ]")

This is my project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQXvm.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html 
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <title>Taco Cloud</title>
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Design your taco!</h1>
    

    <form method="POST" th:object="${design}">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">
      <h3>Designate your wrap:</h3>
      <div th:each="ingredient : ${wrap}">
        <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
               th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
      </div>
      </div>

          <div class="ingredient-group" id="proteins">
      <h3>Pick your protein:</h3>
      <div th:each="ingredient : ${protein}">
        <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
               th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
      </div>
      </div>

          <div class="ingredient-group" id="cheeses">
      <h3>Choose your cheese:</h3>
      <div th:each="ingredient : ${cheese}">
        <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
               th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
      </div>
      </div>

          <div class="ingredient-group" id="veggies">
      <h3>Determine your veggies:</h3>
      <div th:each="ingredient : ${veggies}">
        <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
               th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
      </div>
      </div>

          <div class="ingredient-group" id="sauces">
      <h3>Select your sauce:</h3>
      <div th:each="ingredient : ${sauce}">
        <input th:field="*{ingredients}" type="checkbox"
               th:value="${ingredient.id}"/>
        <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span><br/>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

      <div>


      <h3>Name your taco creation:</h3>
      <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"/>
      <br/>

      <button>Submit Your Taco</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I am getting following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KArGw.png)

I am trying to learn Spring boot. Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: You need to keep scrolling down to find the actual error.  It will tell you the line # in your Thymeleaf that's causing the parse error.  Does your ${design} have a field `getIngredients()`?

Comment: I am using lombok. So, no methods

Comment: @Wiz did you manage to solve this issue? If yes may you please share.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code a form action:

```
 <form method="POST" th:object="${design}" th:action="@{taco/save}">
```

WhiteLabel Error Page is a generic Spring Boot error page that is displayed when no custom error page is present. So you need to setup a page for status 500 error: 
http://zetcode.com/springboot/whitelabelerror/